# Redshift Query Execution Plan

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I noticed that the below query runs slow and after reviewing it in detail, I am wondering why Redshift first scans two tables (Events and Contacts) separetly and then joins them together. The contact table has more than 300,000 rows in there. 
My expectation was that Redshift should first scan the large Events table based on filters specified for it and then finds contacts in there based on Contact_IDs column. Is my expectation incorrect? Is there anything else I can do to speed up the query? I executed Vacuum and Analyze on all tables.

Query:

```
select c.Segment
, Count (Distinct (CASE WHEN et.Event_ID = 1 THEN et.Contact_ID ELSE null END)) as L1
, Count (Distinct (CASE WHEN et.Event_ID = 2 THEN et.Contact_ID ELSE null END)) as L2
from
Events et 
jon contact c on c.Account_ID = et.Account_ID and c.ID = et.Contact_ID
where
et.Account_ID = 5
and et.Event_ID in (1, 2)
and et.IsGuest = 0
and et.dim_date_id >=20151125 
and et.dim_date_id <=20160226
group by c.Segment
order by 1
```

Explain:

```
XN Merge (cost=1000000074927.82..1000000074927.83 rows=1 width=20)
-> XN Network (cost=1000000074927.82..1000000074927.83 rows=1 width=20)
-> XN Sort (cost=1000000074927.82..1000000074927.83 rows=1 width=20)
-> XN HashAggregate (cost=74927.80..74927.81 rows=1 width=20)
-> XN Merge Join DS_DIST_NONE (cost=0.00..74927.57 rows=31 width=20)
-> XN Seq Scan on contact c (cost=0.00..497.56 rows=39805 width=16)
-> XN Seq Scan on eventtransaction et (cost=0.00..6664.84 rows=136 width=20)
```

Comment: @ConsiderMe . . . Redshift doesn't support indexes.  It uses a columnar store.

Comment: Good to know, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The filters are applied only after the join is performed. Incase you want the join to happen after the filters are applied, I would suggest you create a temp table and join it with the contact table as you indicated in your code.

```
select c.Segment
, Count (Distinct (CASE WHEN et.Event_ID = 1 THEN et.Contact_ID ELSE null END)) as L1
, Count (Distinct (CASE WHEN et.Event_ID = 2 THEN et.Contact_ID ELSE null END)) as L2
from
(
  select Event_ID, Account_ID, Contact_ID
  FROM event
  WHERE
    et.Account_ID = 5
    and et.Event_ID in (1, 2)
    and et.IsGuest = 0
    and et.dim_date_id >=20151125 
    and et.dim_date_id <=20160226
)et 
join contact c on c.Account_ID = et.Account_ID and c.ID = et.Contact_ID
group by c.Segment
order by 1
```

Also, you would see good speed improvement on this query, if you have your sortkeys set up on `dim_date_id`. More details about the same can be found [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_best-practices-sort-key.html)

Comment: hey @Abiete, can you upvote this answer if this was useful? Thanks!